# how to get html form data on button click with jquery but the button class and id are same

Tags: jquery

there are 2 form elements i wish to get different form data in jquery variables on button click    please help me or tell me how to get data of two diffrent
fields with unique button but have same id and class.
or  simply tell how add to cart button is added to each product in and sends data back to server uniquely,

HTML

```
<form method="get" id="1">
  <span class="productname">Product1</span>
  <span class="price">100</span>
  <br> Qunatity:
  <input type="text" name="txt" class="quantity" value="3" class="txti" />
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<form method="get" id="2">
  <span id="productname">Product1</span>
  <span id="price">100</span>
  <br> Qunatity:
  <input type="text" name="txt" class="quantity" value="30" class="txti" />
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $().click(function() {
    var txtname = $('.productname').text();
    var textprice = $('.price').text();
    var quantity = $('.quantity').val();
    alert(txtname + " " + textprice + " " + quantity);
  });
});



if all elements will be  in single <form> tag only like:
<form method="get" id="1" >
  <span class="productname">Product1</span>
  <span class="price">200</span>
 <br>Qunatity:<input type="text" name="txt" class="quantity" value="3"        class="txti"/>
  <input type="submit" class="submit"  value="submit" />

<span id="productname">Product2</span>
<span id="price">100</span>
<br>
Qunatity:<input type="text" name="txt" class="quantity" value="30" class="txti"/>
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, each button and other details are placed in separate form, you can use like this,

```
$(".submit").click(function() {
  var txtname = $(this).closest("form").find('.productname').text();
  var textprice = $(this).closest("form").find('.price').text();
  var quantity = $(this).closest("form").find('.quantity').val();
  alert(txtname + " " + textprice + " " + quantity);
});
```

`$(this).closest("form")` will return the parent form of the current clicked button.

`.find()` will get the child elements.

If you want the contents to be placed in a single form, then wrap the inner contents with a parent div like this,

```
<form method="get" id="1">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="productname">Product1</span>
    <span class="price">200</span>
    <br>Qunatity:
    <input type="text" name="txt" class="quantity" value="3" class="txti" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="submit" />
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <span id="productname">Product2</span>
    <span id="price">100</span>
    <br> Qunatity:
    <input type="text" name="txt" class="quantity" value="30" class="txti" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Then the code will be,

```
$(".submit").click(function() {
  var txtname = $(this).closest(".container").find('.productname').text();
  var textprice = $(this).closest(".container").find('.price').text();
  var quantity = $(this).closest(".container").find('.quantity').val();
  alert(txtname + " " + textprice + " " + quantity);
});
```

Comment: it worked..thanks ,but what if i put them in single form then how will i get the values

Comment: how will be the html structure then? put that too in your question.

Comment: it worked too i want 1 more help from you will you please help me

Comment: better you post it as a different question

Comment: i have posted it in this question and seperated it with------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------line

Comment: create a new question and paste the url here.

Comment: it is not letting me ask new question

Comment: it will. You need to change the title.